# mod_rewrite equivalent of a RedirectMatch rule

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have a RedirectMatch rule in my .htaccess file that works fine, but I'm having trouble coming up with a comparable rule using mod_rewrite.

My goal is to have this URL: mysite.com/anything/print show this page: mysite.com/anything?view=print.

The rule that works to Redirect it is this:

```
 RedirectMatch 301 ^(.*)/print/?$ http://mysite.com/$1?view=print
```

But now I'd like to change this from a visible 301 redirect to an "invisible" rewrite using mod_rewrite. I have tried many different variations on this (with and without RewriteBase), and none have worked:

```
 RewriteEngine On
 RewriteBase /
 RewriteRule ^(.*)/print/? $1?view=print
```

What am I doing wrong? Mod_rewrite is definitely enabled, and there are functioning Wordpress-based mod_rewrite rules in the same .htaccess file.

---

**UPDATE**

Using tips from @Nathan, I now have this. However, I still get a 404 when I visit mypost/print.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/index\.php
RewriteRule ^(.*)/print/?$ /index.php/$1?view=print [L]
```

When I append /print/ to a permalink, the WP_Debug plugin indicates the following:

**Request:** `myposttype/mypost/print`

**Query String:** `attachment=print`

**Matched Rewrite Rule:** `myposttype/[^/]+/([^/]+)/?$`

**Matched Rewrite Query:** `attachment=print`

Answer (score 2):

If you have typical wordpress rules in the htaccess file, your rules should come before the `# BEGIN WordPress` block. Otherwise the wordpress rules will stop the rewrite matching before your rules get called.

Also, you should add `$` after your regex pattern unless you also want to match something like: `http://domain.com/page/print/something/else/here`

Lastly, in order for Wordpress to recognize the change in the URL without redirecting the page, you need to append the URL to `index.php/` so that Wordpress will use path info permalinks.

E.g.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/index\.php
RewriteRule ^(.*)/print/?$ /index.php/$1?view=print [L]

# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

Comment: This seems like it should work, but I still get a 404 when I go to domain.com/mypost/print. Using the WP Debug plugin I see that the query is looking for attachment=print (a media attachment with the slug of 'print'). Can you think of any way around this?

Comment: WordPress is going to use the original URL to parse the permalink unless you change the redirect to use path info permalinks like index.php/url/path/here?view=print. I've updated the example to include the path info method.

Comment: Thank you so much for updating. The same 404 and attachment=print query is happening with the updated code; flushing permalinks did not help. Manually inserting index.php (such as mysite.com/index.php/mypost/print) doesn't work either and gives the same 404. Any ideas?

Comment: I've updated the question to show the results from WP_Debug that I get with your new code.

Answer (score 1):

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^(.*)/print/$ /$1?view=print [L]
```

or

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)/print$ /$1?view=print [L]
```

without "/" in the end of URL string